# how to save kendo ui chart to image using PHP or java script

Tags: user-interface, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

> > i would to convert chart to image, iwish that can saving to png or jpeg
> >     how to save kendo ui chart to image using PHP or java script

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these:

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#methods-svg

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#methods-imageDataURL

I've had mixed success with the svg export, but to be fair mine wasn't an "out-of-the-box" scenario.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML 5 you can use this JavaScript:

```js
var image = chart.imageDataURL(); //Kendo UI
var a = $("<a>").attr("href", image).attr("download", "img.png").appendTo("body");      
a[0].click();
a.remove();
```